# undefined method `sass' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration on Heroku

Tags: heroku, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I've looked around a bit and didn't find similar errors reported.
I don't recall having modified my [`production.rb`](https://gist.github.com/1284427). And for good measure, here's my [`application.rb`](https://gist.github.com/3c19d928a8d34d723fa4)

Here's the stack trace from Heroku.

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging --trace

Running rake db:migrate --trace attached to terminal... up, run.2
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53:      warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
rake aborted!

undefined method `sass' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000000047c6fb0>
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:78:in `method_missing'
/app/config/application.rb:63:in `<class:Application>'
/app/config/application.rb:18:in `<module:Instantice>'
/app/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

I initially thought this line in the `application.rb` could be causing this (although it never had before).

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
```

Removing it was fruitless though.

Comment: i think you'll have to post your entire application.rb file

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same error...

I just needed to move the `gem 'sass-rails'` out of the assets group

**Was**

```
#Gemfile
group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails'  # Was giving me errors here.
   ...
end
```

**Is**

```
#Gemfile
gem 'sass-rails'    # No more errors
group :assets do
   ...
end
```

Comment: For me this was not enough. I had to add config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false to config/application.rb as described by heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#troubleshooting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629620/undefined-method-sass-for-railsapplicationconfiguration0x1cf3338-on-st has a nice solution for this. Rather then move sass-rails out of assets, test before running sass config in applicaion.rb.

Answer (score 5):

I spent the entire day yesterday troubleshooting this and managed to fix it. 
I did remove the `config.sass.preferred_syntax` line but it wasn't the only issue.

Most importantly I was missing what seems like a crucial require statement for Sprockets.
Since I'm using RSpec I had commented split up the usual `require "rails/all"` line in my application.rb file into this:

```
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

I can only guess that was an oversight when I upgraded from Rails 3.x to 3.1.x. The correct statement should include Sprockets, as follows:

```
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

I also removed some Compass settings I had gleaned a Chris Eppstein [Gist on using Compass with 3.1](https://gist.github.com/1184843). It was a desperate move but for now I haven't seen any downsides.

**Bear in mind, I had no idea what I was doing. Take this with a grain of salt, I'm simply explaining my "debugging" process.**

Comment: Can you describe the last two things you did in greater detail?  What was the bug with your stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag?  What other config settings did you remove?  I did everything else you described, and am still getting the following error:  rake aborted!
undefined method `sass' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000002d966b8>

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to resolve this if you are also upgrade from a rails 3.0 project:
Just change the lines in config/application.rb from

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

to

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```