# undefined method `sass' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x1cf3338> on Staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to deploy my aplication on server and using staging environment . But its keep  giving me this error on staging environment .

> undefined method `sass' for #Rails::Application::Configuration:0x1cf3338

On my development environment **local** its working fine.
In my application i am using the compass and susy framework , my Gemfile look like this
https://gist.github.com/2003755

I am trying it to configure this from past 2 days , but still not find a way to make it work . Previously this configuration  is working fine . Suddenly after my last deployment every thing broke down .
Thanks

Comment: How do you deploy your application? bundle install is run after the deploy?

Comment: Using capistrano.After every deployment i run bundle install .

Comment: This bundle install is do before your Exception. You have this gem install on your server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're configuring sass from your application.rb then although the sass stuff is only used for asset precompilation (which I presume you are using) Rails will always try and configure sass.

Since in staging the app boots without the assets group loaded, `sass-rails` isn't loaded and so everything falls over. You could either move `sass-rails` to the main bit of your gemfile, or possibly bracket the bit of your `application.rb` which configures sass with

```
if defined?(Sass)
  ...
end
```